# How can I check upvotes vs. downvotes for specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, voting

I have noticed that I am very much on the negative side of votes when asking questions about web development and typically on the upside/neutral when asking other questions.  I don't receive comments on these downvotes, so I want to know if it is me, or if the web development questions are just more down-vote prone.

How can I check the upvote/downvote statistics for stackoverflow based on tags?

Comment: Would be interesting to have  look at the _"c++ shark tank"_'s statistics :-) ...

Comment: You can query the [database](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these really simple [database results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/302351/average-question-score-for-popular-tags), the average question score of really popular tags (I choose `count > 200k`) for web development is actually lower than other development.

```
tagName     tagCount avgScore          
----------- -------- ----------------- 
.net        207145   2.88582173495349  
c++         360382   2.23900531696434  
python      410018   2.07750901849065  
iphone      202501   1.99630615459829  
c#          778058   1.82864263414346  
objective-c 224068   1.63695762779945  
java        832369   1.61043228565936  
javascript  823503   1.49270821568963  
css         295286   1.42374058081449  
android     654054   1.41037179063765  
ios         323279   1.36098410557511  
sql         270644   1.23553016642526  
asp.net     252509   1.2038296271361   
jquery      598931   1.15634105006554  
html        401358   1.13336738634806  
mysql       313738   0.923986114962753 
php         731289   0.828456986725488
```

Comment: So it is true about the web development community being harsher than the rest. Fun fact, I originally posed this question as such, but it got downvoted.

Comment: @Evorlor *"So it is true about the web development community being harsher than the rest."* No, this is a false assumption. Since we don't know anything about the reason of the downvotes, we can't assume something about that community.

Comment: @Tom True.  I should have used the word "statistically".  :-)

Comment: @Evorlor And you should have avoided the word "harsh" :P. We don't know if they are harsh. Maybe these language tags get a lot of bad questions, which "deserves" to be downvoted (where even a lenient user would vote negative). But we don't know that from that statistic :D.